# How to set SwitchCompat disabled but let it be clickable?

Tags: android, switch-statement

I need to use tooltips guide on switch 
when user taps on the view  the tooltip is cleared
but my problem is that its a switch and when user taps on it the status is changed
and I don't want it to happen.

my question is :
how to set SwitchCompat disabled but let it be clickable?

Comment: setup onclick listener and then  set inside     mSwitch.setChecked(false)      mSwitch.setEnabled(false); after onward use some boolean condition as per your logic

Comment: I did it this way , works

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I did what @notTdar said and it worked

this is the answer :

setup onclick listener and then set inside mSwitch.setChecked(false) mSwitch.setEnabled(false); after onward use some boolean condition as per your logic

@notTdar, please write your response as an answer I will delete this one and will accept yours